# How to check if elements in a file names in a folder contain string names in an arraylist of strings?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, directory

I am trying to search through an image folder to check if each image
path in the folder contains String elements from my ArrayList. If the
file path contains the string element, I want to add it to a new
String array. This is what I have so far. The image paths that match
the strings in the array list print out properly in the for loop, but
outside of that it prints null.

```
/*ArrayList content:
   Snow Fall.jpg
   Soft snow.jpg 
   Winter Wonderland.jpg
*/


public void getImages(ArrayList<String> theImagesArrayList) {

    File dir = new File("C:/Users/someone/Desktop/slideshow images");

    int count=0;
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    file = new String[theImagesArrayList.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < theImagesArrayList.size(); i++) {
        for (File b : files) {
            if (theImagesArrayList.contains(b.getName())) {
                    count++;
                    if(count<=theImagesArrayList.size()){
                        file[i] = b.getPath();
                        System.out.println(file[i]);
                        /*Output from above print statement:

                         C:\Users\someone\Desktop\slideshow images\Snow Fall.jpg
                         C:\Users\someone\Desktop\slideshow images\Soft snow.jpg
                         C:\Users\someone\Desktop\slideshow images\Winter Wonderland.jpg
                         */

                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    for(String c: file){
        System.out.println(c);
    }
    /*Output above loop:

      C:\Users\someone\Desktop\slideshow images\Winter Wonderland.jpg
      null
      null
     */
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `count++` is the problem. `file[i] = b.getPath();` is executed all three times in the first outer iteration, and no more in the next ones. So, all the three paths are written in `file[0]`. That's why the `file[1]` and `file[2]` remain null.

Try to `break;` after the `System.out.println(file[i]);` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

The value of variable "i" in the inner loop always 0 in the first iteration, so after the assignment the value of "i" is not incremented, so always it is overridden with the latest value.

In stead of the statement : file[i] = b.getPath();

You can use statement like : file[j++] = b.getPath(); // decalre and initialize j=0 before.